# Looking for documentation on GRASS vectors/topology

Tags: grass-gis, topology

I am looking for documentation (including pictures) of the rationale behind GRASS topology that answers questions like: "What is a topology according to GRASS? How are topologies inferred from geometries, how are nodes, segments and vertices defined?"

So far the internet has let me down in the search, but maybe I missed something.
The best reference I have found is: https://grass.osgeo.org/grass72/manuals/vectorintro.html
but it doesn't really dive into the working of the topology. Ideally there should be something like: https://bost.ocks.org/mike/topology/ (which does not work the same as grass topology).

Comment: This is not answer-worthy but my in-progress exploration using R might be of interest  http://rpubs.com/cyclemumner/sc-rationale  GRASS has a highly sophisticated and optimized topological engine but not an externally-facing fully topological data model, as far as I know. (You are right about D3, that is *arc-node topology*, a normalization of shared boundaries - it's not primitives-based or *simplicial complex* level.)